# what does `terminates option list` mean in python documentation

Tags: python

This might not be a proper place to ask this stupid question. But please let me know the answer.... (In extreme couriosity but cannot understand...)
If you type `Python --help`
There will be something like:

```
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

I literally know what `-m` and `-c` options mean, but ...what does `terminates option list` mean

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question. All that means is that any future options get passed to the program you are providing and not to python. Here is an example

```sh
python3 -m random -v
```

is not verbose but

```sh
python3 -v -m random
```

is verbose.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These are notes for running python from the command line. When it says "terminates option list", it means that "this is treated as the last option in the command".

You could run python with *several* flags, all at once, like so:

```
$ python -O -u -v -m pip install somemodule
```

In this case, the 'option list' would be `-O -u -v -m`. Everything after `-m` is treated as an argument of `-m` (in this case, `pip install somemodule`. If I reordered the command:

```
$ python -m pip install somemodule -O -u -v
```

then `pip install somemodule -O -u -v` would be treated as the argument for the option `-m` - `-u`, `-v`, and `-O` wouldn't be treated as their own options for the `python` executable.

So, when the docs say that `-c` and `-m` terminate the option list, it means that *everything after them is assumed to be an argument for that option*, and not an option for the `python` executable. In other words, if `-c` or `-m` is given, then they will always be the last option for the command, and everything after will be an argument for them.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks~

Comment: So, it is recommended to put `-m` as the last option, right? Since I do not think things like `python -m pip install somemodule -O -u -v
` would be a valid command \o/

Comment: @XinyuLi `pip install somemodule -O -u -v` would indeed not be a valid pip command. The point I'm trying to drive to is that `-m` is _by definition_ the last option - everything else that comes after will be considered as part of it, whether it's its own flag or not.